# Chart.js animation: onComplete event fired on hover

Tags: javascript, events, chart.js

I am loading an image export of my chart after the animation is complete, using the onComplete callback.
My problem is that everytime you hover over the diagram, the onComplete callback is executed an this slows down the page immensely.

Here's my chart code:

```
this.chart = new Chart(this.$chart.getContext("2d"), {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: data,
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },
            animation: {
                onComplete: (e) => {
                    console.log(e);
                    this.initExport();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I checked the Chart.js documentation but I did not find any other option that would only fire after the chart is built. So does anyone know how to distinguish between the hover-animation and the "build"-animation of the chart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace your animation option/object with the following :

```
animation: {
   onComplete(e) => {
      this.options.animation.onComplete = null; //disable after first render
      console.log(e);
      this.initExport();
   }
}
```

Basically, you need to disable onComplete function by setting the `chart.options.animation.onComplete` property to `null`. This will make the onComplete function run only after the chart is rendered for the first time, and prevent it from firing when the chart gets hovered on.

<sub>**TIP :** do **not** use arrow function for object­*'s* method. (`this` will always refer to the `window` object)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Try this. seems you missed function keyword oncomplete:

```
this.chart = new Chart(this.$chart.getContext("2d"), {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: data,
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },
            animation: {
                onComplete: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    this.initExport();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is not the issue, "(e)=>{}" is just another way to write a function in ES6. The advantage of it is that it binds the this-object of the class so I can use class-functions inside.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but solve in a different way (put options: hover: onHover).
Example:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        ..... (other attributes)
    },
    options: {
        onClick: handleClick,
        animation: {
           onComplete: function () { 
                     .... (things the onComplete do) 
           }
        },
        hover: {
            onHover:function(event, chart) {
                if (chart.length > 0)
                    event.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                }   
            },
        }
    });
```